# Add DryIoc adapter for MS DI to Prism DryIoc in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, prism, dryioc

I'm trying to add DryIoc adapter for MS DI to Xamarin.Forms shared library (.net standard class library) but I couldn't yet.

When I run the project I get this error

> 05-20 11:49:29.528 D/        ( 3402): HostConnection::get() New Host
>   Connection established 0xda77ac90, tid 3402 05-20 11:49:29.533 D/Atlas
>   ( 3402): Validating map... Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> 05-20 11:50:18.777 D/Mono    ( 3402): DllImport attempting to load:
>   '/system/lib/liblog.so'. 05-20 11:50:18.777 D/Mono    ( 3402):
>   DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'. 05-20 11:50:18.777
>   D/Mono    ( 3402): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so'
>   ('/system/lib/liblog.so'). 05-20 11:50:18.777 D/Mono    ( 3402):
>   Searching for '__android_log_print'. 05-20 11:50:18.777 D/Mono    (
>   3402): Probing '__android_log_print'. 05-20 11:50:18.777 D/Mono    (
>   3402): Found as '__android_log_print'. Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> 05-20 11:50:18.790 I/MonoDroid( 3402): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 05-20
>   11:50:18.791 I/MonoDroid( 3402): System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. 05-20 11:50:18.791
>   I/MonoDroid( 3402):   at Prism.Common.PageUtilities.GetCurrentPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page mainPage) [0x00002] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\Common\PageUtilities.cs:212  05-20
>   11:50:18.791 I/MonoDroid( 3402):   at
>   Prism.PrismApplicationBase.OnSleep () [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:193  05-20
>   11:50:18.791 I/MonoDroid( 3402):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Application.SendSleep () [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:297  05-20 11:50:18.791
>   I/MonoDroid( 3402):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnStateChanged
>   () [0x00057] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:345
>   05-20 11:50:18.791 I/MonoDroid( 3402):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnStop ()
>   [0x00019] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:293
>   05-20 11:50:18.791 I/MonoDroid( 3402):   at
>   Android.App.Activity.n_OnStop (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in <788a34f7a7b84486905dfde786529d42>:0  05-20
>   11:50:18.791 I/MonoDroid( 3402):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.15(intptr,intptr) 05-20
>   11:50:18.806 W/art     ( 3402): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to
>   register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable

If I remove `IUserSocialService` from MainPageViewModel's constructor works fine. I don't know why not it's injecting the implementation of `IUserSocialService`.

**ServiceLayer**

```
public static IServiceCollection Init()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IUserSocialService, UserSocialService>();
    return serviceCollection;
}
```

**Xamarin.Forms (Shared net standard class library)**

```
protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
{
    var containerExtension = (DryIocContainerExtension)base.CreateContainerExtension();
    containerExtension.Instance.Populate(ServicesLayer.Init());
    return containerExtension; 
}

protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
}
```

**MainPageViewModel**

```
private readonly IUserSocialService userSocialService;

public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IUserSocialService userSocialService) : base(navigationService)
{
    Title = "Main Page";
    this.userSocialService = userSocialService;
}
```

**Packages version:**

Service Layer:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Xamarin.Forms (shared net standard class library)

```
<PackageReference Include="DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Prism.DryIoc.Forms" Version="7.1.0.431" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NRE message is not useful without stack trace. Could you add it?

Comment: @dadhi I edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

By default Prism does not support Microsoft DI. However if this is a need you have you may want to try out the [Prism.Container.Extensions](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions). That project has several helpers available including the ability to handle working with `IServiceProvider` and `IServiceCollection` along with a package to make working with Shiny which uses Microsoft DI completely seamless. You can find the out more on the how to on GitHub.

Comment: There is no package published for Prism.Container.Extensions on MyGet or Nuget. Where can I found it?

Comment: @MauroPetrini it's not on NuGet yet, probably later this week. In the mean time you can install it via MyGet. The feed details are on the ReadMe, and there is a chart to show the latest versions available.

Comment: How to handle scoped services? For example IHttpClientFactory or services.AddHttpClient(). The package not support scoped services.

Comment: Prism in general doesn't deal directly with Scoped services. That project is Open Source. Feel free to create an issue and we can discuss the possibility of adding it there